# Clipboard app that automatically saves to Web share folder?

Tags: images, web, clipboard, picasa

I currently use SnagIt and have used Windows 7 Snipping tools.  These tools allow you to copy a piece of your screen the clipboard and then paste it into other applications on your desktop. They work with Outlook and it's really useful as you don't have to save the image to do a write-up or send an email.

Problem is -  you can't paste clipboard images into webforms. Gmail web does have image insert feature, but it only works on web images that you copied as it extracts the full url from your copy and uses that. It does not work on with images in your local clipboard.

Does anybody know of an application that would allow to clip and save directly to a web folder, maybe something that replaces your clipboard with the URL of the save image location?  It would be awesome if the picasa web client or evernote allowed actual clipboard pasting. Instead they ask for a file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Snagit has addins that allow you send your screencaptures directly from Snagit to the web for easy sharing. You can send your Snagit screen captures to sites like Screencast.com (also made by TechSmith - you get some free hosting space there) and Flickr. You could upload your screen capture to one of those sites with just a click and Snagit would paste the URL to your clipboard.

Screencast.com output: http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/accessories/screencastcom.asp
Flickr output: http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/accessorycategory.asp?catID=1

Answer (score 0):

TinyGrab does it. It's a screenshot capture utility that uploads the image to its hosting service automatically in the background. [tinygrab.com](http://www.tinygrab.com)